# How to use facebook graph API to get nearby restaurants' ratings and checkins?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Does anyone know how to build a graph api query string that is able to fetch the following things:

1. rating information of nearby restaurants that shows in the "Nearby Places" function of iOS  App
2. friends that also had checked in at a specific restaurant

Comment: This page can help https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/